# Please help! Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Installing MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, dpkg

I'm trying to install MySQL with Ubuntu, and I've spent the last 3 days purging MySQL and redownloading to no avail. Most of the solutions I found didn't work for me, and they are all some variation of deleting MySQL and redownloading. I've tried manually going into the files and manually deleting all MySQL related files too.  I've also tried reinstalling some dpkg files, but as you can tell, I'm pretty new to this. How can I fix this?

```
alvin@DESKTOP-DAIIHEJ:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for alvin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                              [ OK ]
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/5: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/6: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/10/fd/7: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/10/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/10/fd/5: Operation not permitted
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 143
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is my error log

```
2022-01-27T22:38:25.061002Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2022-01-27T22:38:25.981554Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-01-27T22:38:26.615434Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 206
2022-01-27T22:38:26.629831Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.648358Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012585] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.648440Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012654] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO disabled.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.787334Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.848746Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
2022-01-27T22:38:26.946919Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2022-01-27T22:38:26.946963Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2022-01-27T22:38:26.948630Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.948712Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-01-27T22:38:26.949587Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Permission denied
2022-01-27T22:38:26.949630Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-01-27T22:38:26.949908Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-01-27T22:38:27.949853Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

Here is the result of `mount | grep proc`

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime) –
```

Comment: `alvin@DESKTOP-DAIIHEJ:~$ sudo mount | grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)`

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. Keep everything in the one place so that it's really easy for everyone to find. I've copied it to your question for you this time.

Answer (score 4):

### There can be Multiple Solutions for the Above

#### 1. Reconfiguring the dpkg Package

One of the triggers of this error is a corrupted dpkg database.
Can be fixed by `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

#### 2. Force Install the Troublesome Package

Sometimes, errors can occur during the installation of software packages. When such happens, you can force install the package using the -f option as shown.

```
sudo apt install -f
OR
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

#### 3. Purge the Bad or Corrupted Software Package

`sudo apt remove --purge package_name`

#### 4. Remove all the Files Associated with the Package

Lastly, you can manually remove all the associated with the troublesome package. First, you need to find these files which are located in the /var/lib/dpkg/info directory.

`sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i package_name`

After listing the files, you can move them to the /tmp directory.

`sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/package-name.* /tmp`

Finally, update the package lists.

`sudo apt update`

And then try to reinstall your Package.

### The Error You are getting is Mysql is unable to install coz port 3306 is already in use.

You could use `netstat -lp | grep 3306` to find out what program is already listening on port 3306 (you should see PID/Program name in last column) and stop that (maybe mysql is already running?).

Alternatively you could start the newly installed server on a different port. (edit `my.cnf` and change the default port there)

Comment: I keep running into the same line after trying all your steps :( 

`dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.15) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: What is your computer Architecture ? I think it's arm or arm64? Or its amd64?

Try ```dpkg --print-architecture``` 
I know it's not a right way to determine architecture but still it will work.

Also try installing Different Versions of MySQL and check if you face same error.

But the Real Error is you already have mysql or any other db tool is installed on your device because your port 3306 is already in use which is default port for db tools like mysql mariadb etc etc.

Comment: Hey, I ran the command and found that my computer Architecture is amd64. Does that mean I have the wrong version? I'll try to find other versions and update if it works then.

Comment: You dont have the wrong version The Error You are getting is Mysql is unable to install coz port 3306 is already in use.
You could use ```netstat -lp | grep 3306``` to find out what program is already listening on port 3306 (you should see PID/Program name in last column) and stop that (maybe mysql is already running?).

Alternatively you could start the newly installed server on a different port. (edit ```my.cnf``` and change the default port there)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the port because I already had a MariaBD instance running in the same instance $vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
port            = 3306
```

for

```
port            = 3366
```

Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the communication language on this site is english, so please translate your post. Also, please indicate what you changed in the `mysqld.cnf` file to solve the problem.

Comment: If you had to change the port that sounds like you've already got an instance of MySQL (maybe MariaDB) running

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer is useful or not. I had this exact problem when installing nodejs 18.
This problem sometimes occurs due to the interference of packages. The following command worked for me

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

And then I installed the package

```
apt install -y -f <package>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

worked for me. I had a package with unmet dependencies.

Comment: This was already mentioned in a previous answer, but you got the order of options wrong.

Comment: The command is valid in this order and worked for me, hopefully it will be useful to other developers.

Comment: Good, then it would be a simple matter describing the difference between `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and `sudo apt install --fix-broken` and why the latter is better.